# How long does it take to install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

For reference, my laptop has an Intel Celeron 540 processor (1.8 Ghz) and 2 GB of RAM. I'm trying to find out if Ubuntu 12.04 takes less than 30 minutes to install, my laptop's battery is total crap and it crashes when it's on and plugged in (it's a sort-of well known hardware issue) and I can't spend the money to get it fixed.

Comment: have you considered taking the battery out all together and plugging in the system directly?

Answer (score 1):

It takes `10-15 minutes` if you switch off the internet (dont download updates and language packs), and if you know what you are doing (have read the guides, and are clear about what to do).

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would suggest [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) and the purchase of a new battery when able. Lubutnu is made for low-end hardware and installs fewer packages meaning that it should be done in under 30 minutes. Don't forget to use the x86 version...

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a minimal install first and afterwards install the desktop.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```